# For boto3, how many client instances should I use?

Tags: python, boto3

When I'm using the boto3 SDK for Python, is it better to have a single client object, like this:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
# use client through the file
```

and then use that everywhere, or should I instantiate it as needed, like this:

```
size = client('s3').head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['ContentLength']
```

Which is better? Does it make a different?

Comment: did you ever find an answer.  Have a similar use case now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any harm using single client object through the file for a particular AWS service. As boto is widely used standard SDK, it won't be changed drastically and even if they make backwards incompatible change, they announce it. So it won't affect your application while running some process.